# How to write file generated in lambda to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using pyqrcode. I want to save the generated QR code to s3 bucket.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-1')
bucket = s3.Bucket('testing-st')
QRobject = pyqrcode.create('123')

with open('image.png', 'wb') as f:
   QRobject.png(f, scale=scale, module_color=[255, 0, 0], background=[0xff, 0xff, 0xcc])
   bucket.upload_file('image.png', 'mykey' )
```

But I am not able to save it to the s3. I have added a role with AmazonS3FullAccess. Please help

```
The error that I am getting is 
[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'youtube-a6eaad.png'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

the error is on line

```
with open('image.png', 'wb') as f:
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: @MarkB I managed to fix the upload issue with AWSLambdaExecute. But  i got an error saying that "errorMessage": "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'youtube-a6eaad.png'",
  "errorType": "OSError",  with error on ` with open(filenamewithextension, 'wb') as f:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to write to `/tmp/image.png`, that is the only folder in the Lambda environment you can write to.

Comment: I am getting timeout error on execution of `QRobject.png(f, scale=scale, module_color=[255, 0, 0], background=[0xff, 0xff, 0xcc])`. any idea :|

Answer (score 0):

Put your image file creation in a try/except first to see if it can create the file successfully.  I did similar type of thing in the past, I saved the file to /tmp and then upload it there after.

So first check to make sure that your file is created and can save out locally to the lambda, it may be due to the location.  Isolate out to see if it's the file creation problem or uploading problem.

Comment: Thanks!, I did and found that there was a permission issue. the error that is currently showing up is  "errorMessage": "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'youtube-a6eaad.png'", "errorType": "OSError", with error on ` with open(filenamewithextension, 'wb') as f:`